# Mongoose: what does it do with not found references?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use Mongoose 4.1.12. My schemas:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String}, // unique nickname
    name: {type: String}
});

var BookSchema = new Schema({
    authors: [{type: String,ref:"User"}] // list of nicknames
});
```

Lets imagine there are 2 Users registered, with nicknames: **igor** and **kristina**.

There is also a Book with authors collection: **igor**, **kristina**, **luke**.

Then I do:

```
Book.findOne({}).populate("authors").exec(function(err,book){...})
```

And a Book now contains only 2 object in "authors" collection, because **luke** user *doesn't exist*.

```
book: {
    authors: [
        { _id: "igor", name: "Igor" }, 
        { _id: "kristina", name: "Kristina" }
    ]
}
```

I expect something like this:

```
book: {
    authors: [
        { _id: "igor", name: "Igor" }, 
        { _id: "kristina", name: "Kristina" },
        "luke"
    ]
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

When populating a ref field, the underlying document which is referenced need not pre-exist.

Also, when the underlying document ref field is not yet populated, and you are retrieving a document with a ref field the value will be :

1. null if your are in .populate(xxx) mode
2. value of ref otherwise

The ref linkage happens at run time

So in your above expected display of find on book, since you are using mode : .populate() that last authors array element 'luke' will appear as null since the underlying 'user' document is missing

Comment: I edited my post to make the question cleaner, could you please take a look again?